# como hacer para que los cambios que realiza el usuario se mantengan después de actualizar la pagina?

Tags: javascript, html, css

esto es lo que hice: Tres botones para que el usuario pueda elegir el background.

```
function cambiarBackground(comp) {
        id_seleccionado = comp.id;
        if (id_seleccionado == "back1") {
            document.querySelector(".grid-container").style.background = "var(--background-1)"
            document.querySelector(".seteos").style.color="white"
        }
    
        if (id_seleccionado == "back2") {
            document.querySelector(".grid-container").style.background = "var(--background-2)"
            document.querySelector(".seteos").style.color="inherit"
        }
        if (id_seleccionado == "back3") {
            document.querySelector(".grid-container").style.background = "black"
            document.querySelector(".seteos").style.color="inherit"
        }
    }
```

pero no se como lograr que al actualizar la pagina se mantengan los cambios.

Comment: Busca información sobre localStorage o sessionStorage de javascript

Comment: Gracias!@masterguru

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba usar localStorage o sessionStorage